# Проблема работы с строками и числами из файла выведенного в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Доброй ночи, есть такая проблема, что не могу считать числа из строк в RichTextBox.(Данные о строках и числах хранятся в файле который я вывожу в RichTextBox);

**Как я получаю данные файла**

```
 DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if(dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + "\n";
                string temp = richTextBox1.Text;
                richTextBox1.LoadFile(file, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                richTextBox1.Text += fileName + temp;
            }
```

**Данные из файлов**

> Math: 10 10 9 7 5 8 9;

> Physics: 9 10 8 5 6 10 7;

> PE: 9 9 9 9 9 10 10;

> IT: 10 6 7 7 7 8 10;

Пытался решить с помощью регулярных выражений но зашел в тупик когда нужно было вытянуть числа уже из коллекции которую сгенерировал MathCollection.

Пытался решить построчно считая с помощью массива:

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Text.Lines; i++)
{
     //Заносилось в массив строк
}
```

Затем полученный массив проверял посимвольно и заносил в новый, но что-то пошло не так и я решил отказаться от данного решения, так как могли возникнуть трудности из-за операций, которые предстоит провести в дальнейшем.(из чисел я должен вычислить среднее арифметическое и поставить на место оценок за предмет и занести в новый RichTextBox, думал что можно будет обойтись richTextBox.AppendText(), но подумал что есть более простое решение)

**Как должно было бы выглядеть занося я данные в новый richTextBox**

> Math:Average;

> Phusics:Average;

> PE:Average;

> IT:Average;

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что вам просто надо из ```Math: 10 10 9 7 5 8 9;``` вычленить все цифры?

Comment: @bubadev, я вот если честно тоже не очень понял задачу... подумал что я такой один и не стал ничего писать (:

Comment: А что сделать-то надо? Среднее арифметическое посчитать среди всех цифр? Или просто вычленить цифры?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял тебе нужно вычленить числа из строки и посчитать среднее арифметическое.

```
            string str = "Math: 10 10 9 7 5 8 9";
            string[] subs = str.Split(' ');
            int numCount = 0;
            int numSum = 0;

            foreach (string s in subs){
                if (int.TryParse(s, out int result))
                {
                    numCount++;
                    numSum += result;
                }else 
                    Console.WriteLine("Non numeric! " + s);
                
            }

            float average =  numSum/numCount;

            Console.WriteLine($"Total numbers: {numCount}; \nNumers sum: {numSum}; \nAverage: {average}.");
```

Comment: Лучше сделать `List<int> numbers` и в него `numbers.Add(result)`, а потом использовать вместо `numCount` длину списка `numbers.Count()`  Помимо этого `Split()` сделает то же самое что и `Split(' ')`

Comment: @bubadev а что изменится при использовании листа? И попоробей, про сплит, пожалуйста. Если можно ссыль на доку в которой это расписано - буду очень признателен